# c++: Proper way to initialize static fields of member struct

Tags: c++, class, struct, static

I got this:

```
// mouse.h
class Mouse {
  private:
    struct Pos {
      static GLfloat x;
      static GLfloat y;
    };    
    static Pos last;
}
```

and this:

```
// mouse.cpp
// 1)
Mouse::Pos Mouse::last = {};
// 2)
Mouse::Pos Mouse::last = { 0.0, 0.0 };
// 3)
Mouse::last.x = 0.0f;
Mouse::last.y = 0.0f;
```

`1)`, `2)` and `3)` are the attempts I've made at initializing that thing. I understand that the header should declare that `last` is `static`, and that the source should initialize it, but something has been wrong with all my attempts. Could someone please tell me the correct way to do such a thing? Am I missing some very important point? Is this nonsense? It is important that the fields are static. Thanks.

Comment: _something has been wrong_ is not a useful problem description. What, exactly, is wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but at least the GLfloats in the embeded struct should most likely not be static.

Comment: The Pos struct is used as a "namespace".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to declare Pos content as static.

```
// mouse.h

class Mouse {
  private:
    struct Pos {
      GLfloat x;
      GLfloat y;
    };    
    static Pos last;
}
```

`Mouse::Pos Mouse::last = { 0.0, 0.0 };`

This should work too

Answer (score 2):

> It is important that the fields are static.

Then `last` will not have any state. It will simply refer to the static `x` and `y` values inside `Mouse::Pos`.

```
#include "mouse.h"

GLfloat Mouse::Pos::x = 10;
GLfloat Mouse::Pos::y = 10;

Mouse::Pos Mouse::last{};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0Qp1EjUUhpoYtO2N)

---

The following asserts pass:

```
assert(Mouse::last.x == 10);
assert(Mouse::last.y == 10);
```